# Android Graph View does not fit within my screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like my graph to fit within my screen. Right now part of the graph to the right falls off the screen, and I'm not able to scroll and see it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_tutorial"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_tutorial_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_results_btn_loadmeasurement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_results_btn_loadmeasurement_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_results_btn_comparemeasurement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_results_btn_comparemeasurement_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_results_btn_measurement_timeline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_results_btn_measurementtimeline_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_results_btn_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_results_btn_menu_text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_spinner_samplenumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_filename"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_filename_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_filename"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_surfacearea"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/tv_surfacearea_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_surfacearea"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_material"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/tv_material_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_material"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_sampleprepby"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/tv_sampleprepby_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_sampleprepby"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_prepstartdatetime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/tv_prepstartdate_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_prepstartdatetime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_prependdatetime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/tv_prependdate_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_prependdatetime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_degastime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_degastime_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_degastime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_degastemp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_degastemp_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_degastemp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_ramptime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_ramptime_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_ramptime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_ramptemp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_ramptemp_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_ramptemp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_soaktime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_soaktime_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_soaktime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_postdegasholdtemp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_postdegasholdtemp_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_postdegasholdtemp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_measuredatetime"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_measuredatetime_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_measuredatetime"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_sampleweight"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_sampleweight_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_sampleweight"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_roomtemp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_roomtemp_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_roomtemp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_atmpressure"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_atmpressure_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_atmpressure"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_measuredby"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_measuredby_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_measuredby"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_slope"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_slope_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_slope"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_intercept"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_intercept_text" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_intercept"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_tv_pearsonfit"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/activity_results_tv_pearsonfit_text" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_results_et_pearsonfit"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                android:id="@+id/activity_results_gv_graph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="550dp"
                android:title="@string/activity_results_gv_title_text" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_results_btn_resetzoom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Reset Zoom" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I expect my graph to fit within my screen. It doesn't seem the graph view is centered within it's layout and is falling off.

Here are some screenshots.

[The Design view. Notice how the "GraphView: No Preview available" text is falling out of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0vl1.png)

[The data gets scrunched up at the end, I can't scroll right to see more of the graph...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9EH5.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing weight. Think of weight similar to a percentage. If I put a weight total of 100 then all total children weight would add up to 100. Of course you don't have to do this, but it is good practice. If you use weight of 1 on the first parent. Then you add a child and say weight of 0.07 you have already claimed 7% of the parent's 1. This leaves 93% for the remaining. On the second child you put weight of 1 aka 100% of the parents weight. So you are attempting to consume 107% of your parent's weight. Then you have a 3rd child element with .06 weight putting you at 113% expectations of your parent.

It's not an exact math, but it's pretty darn close. So do your best to make sure things add up to 100% of the parent's weight sum and you will fit in the screen. Now if you put too many children in there, for example 100 textboxes side by side aren't going to remain visible no matter how much you give them in weight, so you would wrap the screen in a scrollview or pick a better design.

But start with fixing your weight problem and then go from there.

Comment: I see. I fixed the weight of 1 to 0.93 instead. There are only 2 children inside to linear layout from what I see.

However, I still have this issue with the graphview just not centering it's content within it's own layout, and I feel like this has to do with the graph view itself.

Comment: Hi Ishaaq, Centering is done with Gravity or layout_gravity. You must set it on the parent if you want all children to obey it or set it on each child if you want it to set itself. You have not handled this in your layout, so that is why nothing is centering